# having problems updating a particular record in arraylist of java

Tags: java

Ok i made a program that stores information of patients in an array and then asks the user to enter the ID of a patient based on which, the record of that particular patient will be displayed on the screen. Now i have to update the record of the patient that the user enters the ID of but i dont know which statement to use and how to use it.. I believe I can use add and remove but i am not so sure.. Here is my program :- 
right after if(up==1) is where i am having problems thinking what to do.

```
package samplee.java;

import java.util.*;

public class patient$ {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<patientss> patient1 = new ArrayList<patientss>();
        Scanner src = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner stc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sdc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner update = new Scanner(System.in);
        int id, it, num, i;
        String name;
        int ages;
        int id1;
        Boolean leave = false;
        while (!leave) {
            patientss xx = new patientss();
            System.out.println("Enter the patient's ID ");
            System.out.println("-1 to finish entering");
            id = src.nextInt();
            if (id != -1) {
                xx.setId(id);
            }
            System.out.println("Enter the patient's name ");
            System.out.println("-1 to finish entering");
            name = stc.next();
            if (id != -1) {
                xx.setName(name);
                patient1.add(xx);
            }
            System.out.println("Enter the patient's phone number");
            System.out.println("-1 to finish entering");
            num = sdc.nextInt();
            if (id != -1) {
                xx.setNum(num);
                patient1.add(xx);
            } else {
                leave = true;
            }//Escape the while loop.
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the id of a student");
        it = sc.nextInt();
        patientss tt = new patientss();
        for (i = 0; i < patient1.size(); i++) {
            tt = patient1.get(i);
            if (it == tt.getId())
                System.out.println(tt.toString());
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the id of the student you want to update");
        Scanner id11 = new Scanner(System.in);
        id1 = id11.nextInt();
        int up, id2;
        patientss dd = new patientss();
        for (i = 0; i < patient1.size(); i++) {
            dd = patient1.get(i);
            if (id1 == dd.getId()) {
                System.out.println("If you want to change the name, type 1");
                System.out.println("If you want to change the number, type 2");
                System.out.println("If you want to change the id, type 3");
                up = update.nextInt();
                if (up == 1) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And yea this is my patientss class :-

```
package samplee.java;

public class patientss {
    int id;
    String name;
    int num;

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public void setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + id + " " + num;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need five `Scanner` instances for `System.in`. Just use one.

Comment: Your indentation is seriously messed up. Please fix this, your code is unreadable (take a look at the first ``if`` for example). Also: Why do you have 5 scanners on the same inputstream?

Comment: You already extracted the patient into variable `dd`. So use it to call it's setter methods to modify its values.

Answer (score 3):

Please consider using a `HashMap<Integer, Patientss>` instead of an `ArrayList<Patientss>`. This way you can easily look for a patient with its id.

HashMap has get and put implementation that you can use to retrieve and update your objects.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to use ArrayList it's ok, but as @yogidilip wrote, if you need to search objects by Id, the best way is to use HashMap... but an answer for your question is the following:

You need to have a loop method to search the Id in your list, for example

```
//Object to update
patientss patientToUpdate;

for(patientss patient : patient1){  //ObjectType currentObject : ListName
    if(patient.getId() = inputId){
        //Object found
        patientToUpdate = patient;
        //End for when found
        break;
    }
}
```

Then, you have the object in the variable patientToUpdate, and you can set the new values in attributes.

Hope it helps to you.